# Найти месяц по номеру дня в году

Tags: python, calendar

Такой вопрос, допустим я ввожу число от `1 до 365` по этому значению мне нужно узнать в каком месяце находится этот день, если всего `19 месяцев`, в `18` из которых по `20` дней, а в последнем месяце `5` дней
Не могу найти формулу с которой это можно сделать

Comment: у меня тут какая-то есть, может ее ищите `m,d = divmod(n,20)`

Comment: `(n - 1) / 20 + 1`, где `n` - номер дня?

Comment: я перестарался :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, голова не соображает уже)
Вот код:

```
from math import ceil
a = int(input())
month = ceil(a / 20)
print(month)
```